# Creating an object from another class

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

I've spent some time trying to solve this, but clearly I'm missing something because I just can't get the code to work correctly. I currently have a program with three class - person, doctor and ConsoleApplication. Person essentially holds a constructor with information like firstname, lastname, phonenumber etc. Doctor is a subclass of Person as the only extra information I need is their medical specialty - I'm aiming for it to inherit the information in the Person object.

The ConesoleApplication class handles creation of objects from the person and doctor classes, in addition to giving the user a way to modify the objects through input. I've managed to successfully spawn objects of Persons in this class and store them in an array, but I can't figure out how to do the same for the Doctor objects.

Here's an example of the code for the AddNewDoctor method in the ConesoleApplication class. I don't provide inputs for all the fields or store the object in an array because I'm simply trying to test if it works.

```
    private static void AddNewDoctor() {
    int personID = 0;
    Person person; 
        System.out.print("Please enter the identification number of the person that is becoming a doctor: ");

    try {
        personID = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops!! Please enter only integral numbers");
            System.out.println(input.next() + " was not valid input.");
    }

    person = getPersonID(personID);

    if (null == person)
        System.out.println ("This person cannot be found \n");
    else { 
        String spec = null;
        String firstName = null;
        String lastName = null;
        String homeAddress = null;
        String phoneNumber = null;

        firstName = person.getFirstName(firstName);

        System.out.print ("Enter speciality of the doctor: ");  
        spec = input.nextLine();

        Doctor b = new Doctor(firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber, spec);
        System.out.println(b);

    }

}
```

This code will simply result in

```
Identification Number: 0
Name: null
Surname: null
Address: null
Mobile/Telephone: null
```

I was hoping that the object would be created with correct firstName and specialty, but apparently I've done something wrong because they don't appear there. I don't understand why the speciality (spec) field doesn't appear either.

Here's the working code I have for creating objects of the person class - I thought I'd include this just for reference.

```
        private static void AddNewPerson() {
        String firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber;
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter the first name of the person: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();    

        System.out.print ("Enter the last name of the person: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print ("Enter the home address of the person: ");
        homeAddress = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print ("Enter the phone number of the person: ");
        phoneNumber = input.nextLine();

        persons[amountPersons] = new Person (firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber);
        amountPersons++;

        System.out.print ("The new person has been successfully added. " + "\n" 
                           + "" + "\n" );           
    }
```

Here's the constructors for the Person and Doctor classes.

**Person**

```
// Default constructor to initialize default instance variables
public Person()
{
firstName = " ";
lastName = " ";
homeAddress = " ";
phoneNumber = " ";
personNumber = 0;
}

//Overloaded constructor designed for objects to spawn  
public Person (String firstName, String lastName, String homeAddress, String phoneNumber)
{
// Initialize instance variables
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
personNumber = NumberSystem;
NumberSystem = NumberSystem + 1;
}
```

**Doctor**

```
    public Doctor(String firstName, String lastName, String homeAddress, String phoneNumber, String spec) {
    //Constructor with inherited person information and new doctor information
    super(firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber);
    spec = speciality;
    int doctorID = 0;
    personNumber = doctorID;
    }
```

Is there are brave soul out there that is willing to read this all and put me on the correct path? I've gotten very frustrated from trying to figure out why I can't create objects of Doctor correctly. :(

Comment: Where are those printouts coming from? Is it from `System.out.println(b);`? If so, show us `Person.toString()` or `Doctor.toString()`, whichever one is getting called. If not, show us the code that's generating the printouts.

Comment: More broadly, it would really help if you could reduce your code down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve). Remove any code that's not directly relevant to the problem, such as the input prompts and the constructors that aren't being called. Not only would it make your question easier to answer, it would help you isolate the problem.

Comment: can you tell me how are you trying to create Doctor objects? and where?

Comment: You might want to head over to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) with this. There's some big problems in the first dozen lines. E.g. on invalid input you log a message and then continue on as if everything is a-okay.

Comment: @lealand when a question says *I just can't get the code to work correctly*, the last SE site to think of is Code Review; posting non-working code over there is like asking what good books exist about edible flowers over here - code that doesn't work as expected isn't ready for a peer review, and these questions usually get closed in a matter of minutes on CR.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You are correct, I should have added _when you get this to work_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted the fields for Doctor class, but it seems `speciality` is the field and `spec` the parameter passed to constructor. So instead of

```
spec = speciality;
```

it should be:

```
speciality = spec;
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. Turns out that was correct, but turns out I have another issue. I suppose I'll give the best answer to you and create another thread with better code.